# Updating SQLAlchemy multiple rows not working from an scheduled task

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have this model :

class Job(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "job"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
state = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
zipCode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
latitude = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
longitude = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
narrative = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
companyLogo = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
companyName = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
companyURL = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
```

Im trying to update entries older than 14 days as under

```
@classmethod
def deactivate_old_entries(cls)-> "JobModel":
    x_days = date.today() - timedelta(days=14)
    return cls.query.filter(Job.time_created < x_days).\
        update({"active": (False)})
```

I know that the the filter part works ok because it correctly returns the entries older than 14 days , in this case 11 rows

The value returned is 11 indicating in my opinion the correct numbers of rows .But I can see no changes in the column active for those 11 rows.They remains true when they should show false

It looks like the changes are not committed

This is an async task run from a celery scheduled worker.
However  even if I run in from the view in a request from POSTMAN it does the same , meaning it returns 11 but no changes in the column active in the database.

Any idea where is my error ?

Comment: Do you commit? Also, are the readers keeping a transaction open, with an isolation level that prevents them from seeing changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this way

```
def deactivate_old_entries()-> "JobModel":
    nigthy_days = date.today() - timedelta(days=14)
    db.session.query(Job).filter(Job.time_created < nigthy_days).\
        update({"active": (False)})
    db.session.commit()
```

And it worked fine.